# Как в плагине jqueryvalidation настроить собственные регулярные выражения для валидации?

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация, плагин

[jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org)

Из документации ничего не пойму. Такое ощущение, что эта возможность по логике должна быть просто в

```
$('form').validation({
rule(

);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом плагине нет стандартного метода валидации, который бы позволял указывать собственные регулярные выражения, но его можно добавить самостоятельно:

```
$.validator.addMethod('regexp', function(value, element, params) {
    var expression = new RegExp(params);
    return this.optional(element) || expression.test(value);
});
```

А использовать вот так:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            regexp: /^[a-z]+$/
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[jQuery.validator.addMethod()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod( name, method [, message ] )
```

> Пример: добавить метод проверки, который проверяет, начинается ли
>   строка с имени определенного домена.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domain", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^http:\/\/mycorporatedomain.com/.test(value);
}, "Please specify the correct domain for your documents");
```

---

**[jQuery.validator.methods](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.methods/)**

Описание: Объект, содержащий все методы проверки, известные валидатору. Может быть использован, чтобы переопределить отдельные методы, сохраняя сообщения по умолчанию.

> Пример. Устанавливает настраиваемый шаблон электронной почты для
>   встроенного правила проверки электронной почты.

```
$.validator.methods.email = function( value, element ) {
  return this.optional( element ) || /[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/.test( value );
}

$('form').validation({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавь [`additional-methods.js`](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js) или [`pattern.js`](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/additional/pattern.js) и плагин jQuery Validation будет использовать HTML5 атрибут [`pattern`](https://webref.ru/html/input/pattern).

```
<input type="text" name="somename" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myform').validate({
    debug: true
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="fullname" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}" required="required" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```